# read local binary file in javascript using html5 file api

Tags: javascript, html, fileapi

My problem is, that the content, that I am reading from a local binary file (pdf-file) using javascript is not exactly the file's real content. There are subtile but important differences. I guess it is a bug in the implementation of `readAsBinaryString` in the html5 file api.

Here is the html-code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>read local file</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="file" id="fileInput">
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is the content of the file test.js:

```
var clickLoadPdf = function (file) {
    if (file.name.match(/\.pdf$/)) {

        //create Reader
        var reader = new FileReader();

        // Closure to capture the file information.
        reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
            return function(e) {

                //this is the file's content (or should be)
                var content = e.target.result;
                e=e; //set a breakpoint on this instruction


                //call a function where `content` is
                //sent to the server via AJAX

                //sendToServer(content);

            };

        })(file);

        // Read in the pdf file as a binary string.
        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    }
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    //attach eventhandler
    $('#fileInput').on('change', function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();
        if (evt.target && evt.target.files.length) {
            clickLoadPdf(evt.target.files[0]);
        }
    });
});
```

Load the html-file into your browser (i used Safari on a Mac), and inspect elements. In the debugger find the remark `//set a breakpoint on this instruction` within the JavaScript file and set a breakpoint on it. Then go the the representation of the html-file in your browser, click the input-button and select any pdf-file.

One line above the breakpoint the variable `content`now should contain the content of the pdf-file, and at first view, it all looks fine. But when I uploaded it to my server and stored it there, the result was a pdf-file, that could be opened, but was corrupt, since it showed only a white page without any content.

I was searching for the error, and found out, that in the JavaScript-file the html5 file api did not return the 100% exact content of the local pdf-file. Some bytes are missing.

Look at this example of the beginning of an pdf-file.

This is the original file (pay attention to the last line displayed here, which is `xœí½`):

```
%PDF-1.3
%âãÏÓ
1 0 obj
<</CreationDate (D:20131210124436)/Creator (AS-PDF 0.3.0 by Anton Scheffer)/Producer (running on Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production)/Title <FEFF>/Author <FEFF>/Subject <FEFF>/Keywords <FEFF>>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<</Type/Font/Subtype/Type0/Encoding/Identity-H/BaseFont/UMHTEK+ZurichBT-Roman/DescendantFonts 3 0 R/ToUnicode 10 0 R>>
endobj
3 0 obj
[4 0 R]
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Type/Font/Subtype/CIDFontType2/CIDToGIDMap/Identity/DW 1000/BaseFont/UMHTEK+ZurichBT-Roman/CIDSystemInfo 5 0 R/W 6 0 R/FontDescriptor 7 0 R>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<</Ordering(Identity) /Registry(Adobe) /Supplement 0>>
endobj
6 0 obj
[0 [600] 3 [276 370] 11 [314 314 527] 15 [276 331 276 300 553 553 553 553 553 553 553 553 553 553 370] 35 [1000 712 641 662 723 604 549 744 713 263 527 649 535 909 733 770 603 770 647 655 603 728 657 977] 61 [602] 68 [530 602 516 602 550 308 592 587 250 250 496 250 912 587 602 600] 85 [370 491 316 587 542 810 545] 93 [438] 98 [712] 103 [770] 108 [530] 124 [602] 129 [587] 137 [644] 178 [500] 180 [437] 197 [437]]
endobj
7 0 obj
<</Type/FontDescriptor/FontName/UMHTEK+ZurichBT-Roman/Flags 32/FontBBox [-167 -236 1265 963]/ItalicAngle 0/Ascent 963/Descent -236/CapHeight 963/StemV 50/FontFile2 8 0 R>>
endobj
8 0 obj
<</Filter /FlateDecode /Length 29200/Length1 43660>>
stream
xœí½
```

This is the content of the JavaScript-variabel `content`:

```
%PDF-1.3
%âãÏÓ
1 0 obj
<</CreationDate (D:20131210124436)/Creator (AS-PDF 0.3.0 by Anton Scheffer)/Producer (running on Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production)/Title <FEFF>/Author <FEFF>/Subject <FEFF>/Keywords <FEFF>>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<</Type/Font/Subtype/Type0/Encoding/Identity-H/BaseFont/UMHTEK+ZurichBT-Roman/DescendantFonts 3 0 R/ToUnicode 10 0 R>>
endobj
3 0 obj
[4 0 R]
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Type/Font/Subtype/CIDFontType2/CIDToGIDMap/Identity/DW 1000/BaseFont/UMHTEK+ZurichBT-Roman/CIDSystemInfo 5 0 R/W 6 0 R/FontDescriptor 7 0 R>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<</Ordering(Identity) /Registry(Adobe) /Supplement 0>>
endobj
6 0 obj
[0 [600] 3 [276 370] 11 [314 314 527] 15 [276 331 276 300 553 553 553 553 553 553 553 553 553 553 370] 35 [1000 712 641 662 723 604 549 744 713 263 527 649 535 909 733 770 603 770 647 655 603 728 657 977] 61 [602] 68 [530 602 516 602 550 308 592 587 250 250 496 250 912 587 602 600] 85 [370 491 316 587 542 810 545] 93 [438] 98 [712] 103 [770] 108 [530] 124 [602] 129 [587] 137 [644] 178 [500] 180 [437] 197 [437]]
endobj
7 0 obj
<</Type/FontDescriptor/FontName/UMHTEK+ZurichBT-Roman/Flags 32/FontBBox [-167 -236 1265 963]/ItalicAngle 0/Ascent 963/Descent -236/CapHeight 963/StemV 50/FontFile2 8 0 R>>
endobj
8 0 obj
<</Filter /FlateDecode /Length 29200/Length1 43660>>
stream
xí½
```

The difference is in the last line dislayed here. In the original file it starts with `xœí½`, but the variable contains `xí½` So the `œ` between `x` and `í` disappeared. And `xí½` is exactly what I found in the file that was stored on the server.

How can I fix this?

Is there an other way to automatically upload a pdf-file to a server just by selecting it?

Comment: First hit on google: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/

Comment: @SzabolcsPáll: How does this solve my problem? My problem occurs at **reading the local file**; your link describes techniques to upload files to a server. I have no problem with uploading or xhr. (Did you read my question?)

Comment: "Is there an other way to automatically upload a pdf-file to a server just by selecting it?" - @HubertSchonlast <- Solves this.